# console.log a GET request with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the Express framework for my node application. I'm quite new to it so I thought I'd create a defacto "To-Do" application to learn about it. What I'm trying to do it log a request made for debugging purposes. So when I go to:

```
app.get('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
    var result = db.load(req.params.id);
    result ? res.send(result) : res.send(404);
});
```

I want to a) see what `result` equals and b) log what happens in my `db.load` method:

```
exports.load = function (id) {
    todos.findOne({ id: id }, function (err, todo) {
        if (!err) {
            return todo;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using the `mongolian` library to access my MongoDB data. I've followed an example by Steve Sanderson: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/nodejs-webmatrix-video-tutorials

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear why you can't just do what you described.

Comment: When I put a `console.log` where ever I put it, it doesnt appear, so I can put `console.log("Hello")` in my `load` method or `get` method and nothing appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
    db.load(req.params.id, function(err, result) {
        // also handle err
        result ? res.send(result) : res.send(404);
    });
});


exports.load = function (id, callback) {
    todos.findOne({ id: id }, callback);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer, since the asker is apparently confused by async control flow.

Comment: When I pass in `req.params.id` I get a 404, but if I hard-code a value (eg: 1) it'll return that object. If I put a `console.log(req)` to see that values, nothing appears?

Comment: Well.. I figured it out.. I had to do: `db.load(parseInt(req.params.id)..`